# Using Spring.IO dependency management, how can I override the version of a particular jar?

Tags: spring, gradle, dependency-management

I'm making use of the aws java sdk that relies on a jackson version that is greater than what is in the spring bom, I need to be able to override the version (to use a version more compatible with the aws sdk). How can I override the version of a particular jar?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://mvnrepo.----.net/nexus/content/groups/public/" }    
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = 1.0

repositories {
    maven { url "https://mvnrepo.-----.net/nexus/content/groups/public/"}    
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.4.RELEASE'
    }
}
dependencies {


    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context',
            'org.springframework:spring-core',
            'org.springframework:spring-test',
            'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.10.+',
            'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.10.+',
            'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.10.+',
            'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:1.10.+',
            'com.google.code.gson:gson',
            'joda-time:joda-time',
            'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12',
                'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.7'
}
```

Comment: Figured it out! Though this is for a base project, would like for the override to be honor by projects that consume this one.

Answer (score 2):

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.4.RELEASE'
    }
    dependencies {
        dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.3'
        dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.3'
        dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it would be nice how to do this in a multi-project build context so that not every consuming project needs to apply this.